# What is SQL's "Having" equivalent in Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

How can I write an equivalent code in Pandas of:

```sql
SELECT 
a
,b
,MAX(c) as MAX_c
,DT_FIN_VERSN
from T
group by a,b
Having c = Max_c
```

I tried this:

```py
g = df.groupby('a','b')  

g.filter(lambda x: max(c) == c)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's unclear from your SQL what you actually want. Does that `having` actually do anything? If you're looking to select the single row from the group where `c` is the group's maximum value of `c`, isn't that just... `max` on its own?

Comment: Does the SQL even run? `DT_FIN_VERSN` needs to be in the group expression or be the subject of an aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment above pointed out, SQL statement looks problematic to me as well.

In pandas, it would be like :

Lets say 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'DT_FIN_VERSN' are column names in your DF. Group by 'a' and 'b', and calculate the maximum 'c' for each group

```
grouped = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).agg({'c': 'max', 'DT_FIN_VERSN': 'first'})

# filter the groups to only include rows where 'c' matches the maximum 'c'

result = grouped[grouped['c'] == grouped['c']]

result.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

[.Agg reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)

Answer (score 0):

**This is SQL query. right!**

In pandas, you can achieve the equivalent of the given SQL query using the groupby and agg functions.

```
import pandas as pd



# Example data 

data = {
    'a': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'b': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
    'c': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    'DT_FIN_VERSN': ['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-04-01', '2021-05-01']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Group by 'a' and 'b', Aggregate using MAX(c)
aggregated_df = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].agg(MAX_c='max').reset_index()

# Filter rows where c is equal to MAX_c

result_df = aggregated_df[aggregated_df['c'] == aggregated_df['MAX_c']]

print(result_df)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer : when I run your code I get this error :

Comment: Thanks, when I run your code I get : KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3628             try:
-> 3629                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630             except KeyError as err:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()


KeyError: 'c'